# How to determine if a set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently enrolled in a Linear Algebra course and we have started our study on vectors and vector spaces. One of the problems that I am having a difficult time understanding is:

Determine whether each set equipped with the given operations is a vector space using the 10 vector space axioms.
The set of all pairs of real numbers of the form (x, 0) with the standard operations on R^2.

My attempt at this problem is:
u = (u1, 0);
v = (v1, 0)

u + v = (u1, 0) + (v1, 0)

```
    = (u1 + v1, 0 + 0)

    = (u1 + v1, 0) which has the form (x, 0)
```

Is this correct, or have I totally missed what is being asked? Have I identified my vectors u and v to be correct, or should I use the vectors u = (u1, u2); v = (v1, v2), since I am in R^2

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: This is correct as is -- Congrats. You just proved that this set is closed under vector addition.

Comment: Just a note: if you know that your set is a subset of a vector space (with the same operations as the vector space), then you don't need to verify all $10$ of your axioms.  Most of them are inherited by the fact that your set is a subset of a vector space.  The only $2$ you *do* need to check are closure under vector addition and closure under scalar multiplication. -- So for this one, there's just one more to go. :)

Comment: @Bye_World: The empty set satisfies those two conditions but it isn't a vector space.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese How do you define on operation on the empty set? -- I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: @Bye_World: You restrict the addition and scalar multiplication operations from the vector space. The point is that there are three conditions to check whether a subset of a vector space is itself a vector space, the two you mention and that the subset it is non-empty (or equivalently, it contains the zero vector).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Good to know, gracias.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. My thinking is that since the question is based on all real numbers in R^2, then it is basically the same as saying that u1 + v1 = x.